# Spring Data JPA Query method to find all objects with empty list property

Tags: java, collections, spring-data-jpa, is-empty

I have an entity which contains a property that is a list:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sales.jobs")
public class Job {
    ...
    private List<Shipment> jobShipments;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="sales.jobs_shipments",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_jobid", referencedColumnName="pk_jobid"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_shipmentid", referencedColumnName="pk_shipmentid"))
    public List<Shipment> getJobShipments() {
        return jobShipments;
    }

    public void setJobShipments(List<Shipment> jobShipments) {
        this.jobShipments = jobShipments;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the repository, I would like to have a query method which returns all jobs where `jobShipments` is an empty list.  I had first tried the `IsNull` keyword as shown below, but that doesn't work because if there are no shipments it is an empty list rather than null.

```
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<Job, Integer> {
    Page<Job> findByJobShipmentsIsNull(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I looked through the keywords in the documentation hoping to find something like `IsEmpty`, but I couldn't find anything that looked right.

I am looking for an answer that uses keywords rather than writing out a query, but I suppose that would be the fallback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there're keywords `IsEmpty` and `Empty` for collections:

```java
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<Job, Integer> {
    Page<Job> findByJobShipmentsIsEmpty(Pageable pageable);
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="sales.jobs")
public class Job {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="sales.jobs_shipments",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_jobid", referencedColumnName="pk_jobid"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="fk_shipmentid", referencedColumnName="pk_shipmentid"))
    private List<Shipment> jobShipments = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
}
```

See [Appendix C: Repository Query Keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed the appendix somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, `IsNull` is actually working.  I checked `IsNotNull` for a point of reference, and it gave me all the jobs that did have shipments.  I then ran this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales.jobs AS jobs
    LEFT JOIN sales.jobs_shipments AS ship ON jobs.PK_JobID = ship.FK_JobID
WHERE ship.FK_ShipmentID IS NULL;
```

The count from that query matched the result from the `IsNull` repository query.  So even though it is returning an empty array, it is still finding the null entries just like my query.